# UITextField is not working programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I created `UITextField` programmatically all is working good but my `UITextField` is not editing, i.e when I try to tap on `UITextField` its not working here my sample code,

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(16, 281, 288, 47);
cycle  = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
cycle.placeholder = @"Cycle Number";
cycle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
cycle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
cycle.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
cycle.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
cycle.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
cycle.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
cycle.delegate = self;
cycle.text = @"";
[self.view addSubview:cycle];
```

Comment: it is working no..whats the issue?Is it that u r not able to see the textfield when trying to edit?

Comment: its working bro but when i try to tap my textfield its not working my keyboard not loading i thinking i have left something tats y my textfield is non edititable

Comment: Delete the App from simulator and clean the build then execute again if again problem persists check for your hardware keyboard

Comment: i tried but still its not working

Comment: try bringing the subview in front it might be under some view [self.view bringSubviewToFront:cycle];

Comment: how can u suggest some code

Comment: Looks like the problem is in superview. Try to add self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;  Or editing isdisallowed in delegate. Try to comment //cycle.delegate = self;

Comment: @user3458924 what is this comment supposed to mean?? :) :)

Comment: okie i got output simple mistake i have done i removed cycle.delegate=self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)];   textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textField.placeholder = @"enter text";
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
textField.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textField];'

Below delegate methods must use

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [self endEditing];
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;

}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
        [self beginEditing:textField];
}

 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {


     // [self endEditing];
}



 I hope you it is useful for u
```

Comment: How is this different than the OP's code and why do you think this is better? Good answers accompany code samples with an explanation for future readers.

Comment: #Stonz2  nice question, :-)      ohhh sorry i didn't check the above answer, both are same.That's my mistake.but i Explain that  we are using delegate option so must add textfield delegate in our view controller,Using delegate is one of the best way to declare objectives in xcode.So i think it's a one of the answer your question.I hope you understand.we have lot of ways to create textfields in xcode.with out declaring Delegate also we create textfields.